# Number of inactive connection pools

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my application I have problem with pooled conections leaks.

About every 3 weeks the pool limit is exhausted and the application server needs to be restarted.  Observing performance counters from group '.Net Data provider for Sql server' for my application I noticed that sometimes the value of counter `NumbeOfInactiveConnectionPools` increases by 1 for a short period of time (about 30 seconds) and them decreased back to what it was.  Occasionally it increases by 1 and doesn't decrease.  The long term value becomes 1. Then it continues to increase by 1 and decreased back.  As a result, now long term value is 2.

Is this the reason that the connection is leaking?  Could somebody explain to me what this counter means and when connection pool become inactive?  I found a description of the counter that I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it is poor.

Comment: Are all of your connections implementing `using` statements?

Comment: You exceed number of connections in pool or number of pools? I didn't quite get that. And what is the symptom? Do You get any exceptions?

Comment: @msmucker0527: yes, I dispose all connections.

Comment: @Grzegorz Wilczura: I exceed number of connections in pool. As I result, I got exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.   This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: @DmitryPhilippov Can you add your connection string (with fake credentials of course) or strings if you have many?

Comment: @Grzegorz Wilczura connection string looks like 'Data Source=SqlServerAlias;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'

Answer (score 0):

NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools doesn't seem to have anything to do with number of current connections.
You would have to monitor number of active connection pools and number of active connections.

I don't understand why you would need to restart your application server (is you app hosted on IIS?) - you might not have free connections now - but you should have them in time.

Unfortunately exceeding pool size can be caused by poor application design.
You should check if your exception is being thrown always by some specific part of code or does it happen randomly.

If it's always the same code - you should redesign this functionality.
If it's random then change MaxPoolSize in your connection string to bigger number.